# What's the best method for detecting tags with PHP?

Tags: php, regex, performance

I would like users to be able to insert tags like the following:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, {module_user_name, 123} consectetur adipiscing elit.
```

As you can see in the example above, the tag has a couple of arguments.  The first being the function required, and the arguments will depend on the function requested.

So I would use regex to detect the { and }, feedback?  I would then grab the first argument and check to see if it exists.

If it does exist, I would use a good naming convention to avoid having to use a massive IF ELSE or switch script.  Like module_user_name would fire the moduleUserName() function, or something like that, feedback?

** This is just my thoughts on how to solve this problem and I'm just wondering if anyone could improve it or point out any issues with speed etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume by tags you mean some form of plugin markup. Then the `{` syntax is a bit too lightweight, it might easily conflict with regular text; whyfor the replacing should be done cautiosly. A good trick here would be to use `preg_replace_callback()` like so:

```
 $html = preg_replace_callback('/\{([\w\s,\d]+)\}/', "tags_", $html);

 function tags_($call) {

     // split up
     $func = explode(",", $call[1]);
     $func = array_map("trim", $func);

     // test for handler existence
     if (function_exists($func[0])) {
         return call_user_func_array(array_shift($func), $func);
     } 

     return $call[0];   // do not replace
 }
```

Here the named user function would just be invoked if it exists. If there is something like `{wacky text 123}` found, then the callback would just return it and thus leave the original `$html` unaltered.

Comment: Firstly, I forgot to say thanks for your feedback back in December. I must have been too busy to reply.

Secondly, I'm not too great with regex, if I want multiple arguments like {module_name, 123, ABC, 1A2B}, {module_name, ABC, 1} etc. What do I need to change the regex to?

Comment: That regex should already work. The callback however contains an error, it should say `if (function_exists($func[0])) {`. Or did you get another error?

Comment: mate, my apologies 

I didn't test the regex supplied and made an assumption on what I saw, all works well !

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be pretty close to what Mario has already given you, but I would add:

- you should be a more detailed with the regex so that things that don't look like functions are ignored (e.g. {12345})
- if you really must have a translation of "module_user_name" to "moduleUserName", then you should set this up as an array, not a switch:

  $tags = array(
          /* user tag        =>  php function */
          'module_user_name' => 'moduleUserName',
          'module_user_id'   => 'getUserId',
          // etc
          );
  if (isset($tags[$func])) {
      call_user_func($tags[$func], ...)
  }

The reason to avoid switch() is because it's executed like a bunch of if/elseif statements and it takes longer to reach cases at the bottom, whereas an array has constant lookup time (i'm pretty sure that's the case).

- If you don't want to maintain a giant array (i wouldn't), then just decide on a prefix that you will use for every user tag, such that `{module_user_name, 123}` translates to php `USER_TAG_module_user_name(123)` and only call functions starting with `USER_TAG_`.
- Don't forget to provide a way for users to put a `{` in without it getting turned into something else (i.e., use `{{` or `\{`)

Comment: I definitely don't want to create a giant array, I would like items to be as seamless as possible to avoid mistakes etc.

It's best to rewrite the tag from 'module_user_name' to 'moduleUserName' and see if the function exists, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

> If it does exist, I would use a good
>   naming convention to avoid having to
>   use a massive IF ELSE or switch
>   script. Like module_user_name would
>   fire the moduleUserName() function, or
>   something like that, feedback?

That sounds like a variation on an autoloader where each name maps to a class/function. If you have complete control over the naming, that shouldn't be a problem. If you have to support existing tags and/or the naming convention isn't consistent, you'll need a switch statement or similar.

In fact, this is similar to how Smarty makes its function calls. As opposed to writing your own parser, you might explore that one. It's implementation is well-establish and probably better than what you'd write the first time around.